# Подключение Json и вложенный массив

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, json

Доброго времени суток. Впервые работаю с .json. Раньше обходился БД, но сейчас нужен именно он. 
Вопроса 2 и состоят в следующем:
1. Как подключить локальный data.json файл к действующему коду.
2. Как обращаться к вложенным массивам( и так и так пробовал, не получается)

```
<style>
*{
    font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
<?
$cityFrom = $_GET['cityFrom'];
$cityTo = $_GET['cityTo'];
trim($cityFrom);
trim($cityTo);
$errorState = 0; //All is good;

if($cityFrom == $cityTo)
{
    $errorState = 1; //Same citeis;
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\"> alert(\"Entered same cities / Введены одинаковые города\"); window.location.href = \"order.html\"; </script>";
}
if($cityFrom != "Kazan" && $cityTo != "Kazan")
{
    $errorState = 2; //Not exist way;
}

?>

<script language = "javascript" >
    //Вызов json из "data.json"
</script>
```

Json файл заполнен для 1 города и выглядит следующим образом:
(Как мне изъять оттуда city.Kazan.Ufa[0]; что-то типа того)

```
{
"city": [
    {
        "Kazan": [
            {
                "Ufa": ["8:00", "10:00", "11:00", "13:00", "16:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"], 
                "Izhevsk": [], 
                "Chelny": [], 
                "Elabuga": [], 
                "Nizhnekamsk": [], 
                "Almet": [], 
                "Ulyanovsk": [], 
                "Samara": [], 
                "Tolyati": [], 
                "Moscow": [], 
                "SP": [], 
                "Yoshkarola": [], 
                "Kirov": [], 
                "Novgorod": []
            }
        ],
        "Ufa" : [
            {
                "Kazan": ["6:00", "8:00", "10:00", "14:00", "18:00", "21:00", "22:00", "00:00"]
            }
        ],
        "Izhevsk": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Chelny": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Elabuga": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Nizhnekamsk": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Almet": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Ulyanovsk": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Samara": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Tolyati": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Moscow": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "SP": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Yoshkorola": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Kirov": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
        ],
        "Novgorod": [
            {
                "Kazan": []
            }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: "Впервые работаю с .json. Раньше обходился БД" и как это связано с БД?

Comment: А разве было сказано, что тема про БД? А так уж, отвечая на вопрос, в БД, как ни странно, тоже можно данные хранить.

Answer (score 2):

Например вот так:

```
//Вместо data.json укажите свой путь
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');

$json = json_decode($data);

print_r($json->city[0]->Kazan[0]->Ufa[0]);
```